# use pytest.fixture to set class-variable in a class test

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to use a fixture in a non-test function e.g for setting a variable in a class-test during `setup_class`

```py
#conftest.py
import pytest
import random
import string


@pytest.fixture(scope = "session")
def run_id():
    random_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))
    _run_id = "fail_fast_" + random_id
    return _run_id
```

and then a test-file

```py
#test.py

import pytest
import os


def get_run_id(run_id):
    return run_id


class TestTrainingAndValidationPipeline:
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls._run_id = get_run_id() # fails "TypeError: get_run_id() missing 1 required 
                                   #          positional argument: 'run_id'"

        print(f"Setting up {cls._run_id}")
    
    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
       print(f"Tearing down {cls._run_id}")

    def test_attribute_change(self):
        print("hello")
        self._run_id= "world"
        print(self._run_id)
```

in case we cannot set a class-attribute like this, how could I then retrieve the `run_id` using `get_run_id` (since that could solve the issue too)

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures can only be used [in tests or in other fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#how-to-use-fixtures).

If your real code is similar (regarding the fixture) to the shown example, you won't need to put the fixture result into a class variable - the standard way is to just use fixtures directly where needed:

```py
class TestTrainingAndValidationPipeline:
    def test_attribute_change(self, run_id):
        print("hello")
        print(run_id)
```

Note that the fixture function would only be executed once per test session (being session-scoped). The requested fixture will just provide the cached result of that function.

If you really need to put some value depending on the fixture into a class variable, you can do this by using a class-scoped fixture instead of a normal class method:

```py
class TestTrainingAndValidationPipeline:
    
    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(cls, run_id):
        cls._run_id = run_id
        print(f"Setting up {cls._run_id}")
        yield
        print(f"Tearing down {cls._run_id}")

    def test_attribute_change(self):
        print("hello")
        print(self._run_id)
```

Note that in the case of a session-based fixture this does not make much sense, as the fixture will yield the same result for all tests in all test classes. Even if that was not the case (e.g. there is a class specific part) you would still usually use the fixture directly, e.g.:

```py
class TestTrainingAndValidationPipeline:
    
    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def class_id(cls, run_id):
        yield run_id + cls.__name__  # something class-based...

    def test_attribute_change(self, class_id):
        print("hello")
        print(class_id)
```